# Is there a way to tell ffmpeg to speed up a video so its duration matches the duration of the audio?

Tags: ffmpeg

Just as the title describes; is there a simple way to tell ffmpeg to take in video and audio tracks and to speed up (or slow down, I suppose) the video so that it matches the duration of the audio? I can calculate PTS values but have no idea how to do it in an automated way.

Comment: No automatic way.

Comment: Can probe the duration of the streams first and then use the values in a setpts expression and maybe use minterpolate/atempo?